# Entity Framework grouping by column from join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the next query:

```
select VisitLines.ProcedureId, COUNT(DISTINCT VisitLines.VisitId) as nt
from Visits
LEFT JOIN VisitLines ON Visits.Id = VisitLines.VisitId
WHERE Visits.VisitStatusId = 1 AND Visits.IsActive = 1 AND VisitLines.IsActive = 1 
GROUP BY VisitLines.ProcedureId
```

1. Main question: Does ability exists  to grouping by column from join using linq ? I'm wondering how to do it using 'collection' column.
2. Is it possible to force EF to generate COUNT(DISTINCT column) ? IQueryable.GroupBy.Select(x => x.Select(n => n.Number).Distinct().Count()) generate query with few subqueries which much slower then COUNT(DISTINCT )

Comment: about 2:
I didn't find how to generate COUNT(DISTINCT column), but found the way how to generate more efficient query then using linq:
IQuaryable.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Number}).GroupBy(x => x.Key.Id)
.Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count })
it generate GroupBy with only one subquery 'select distinct' which is more efficient than query from standard linq approach Dictinct().Count().But I still want to know if it is possible to generate sql COUNT(DISTINCT column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. Need to use `SelectMany` with second parameter `resultSelector`:

```
dbContext.Visits.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                .SelectMany(x => x.VisitLines, (v, vl) => new
                {
                  v.Id,
                  vl.ProcedureId
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.ProcedureId)
                          .Select(x => new
                          {
                              Id = x.Key,
                              VisitCount = x.Count()
                          }).ToArray();
```

It generates the desired SQL, but with exception that I need distinct count by visit.

And if I change `VisitCount = x.Distinct().Count()` then EF generates a query with few subqueries again. But the main issue resolved